# Can you call a method in the SuperClass from a separate class that has the SubClass of said SuperClass as an object?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

This SubClass has overridden the original method and the SuperClass is of an abstract class. Is it possible to call the original method in the SuperClass through an object which is initialized to it's subclass?

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("SubClass: methodA");
    }

    public void methodB(int num) {
        System.out.println("SubClass: methodB " + ++num);
    }
}

public abstract class SuperClass {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("SuperClass: methodA");
    }

    public void methodB(int num) {
        System.out.println("SuperClass: methodB " + num);
    }
}
```

What im trying to do:

```
{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    SuperClass sup= new SuperClass();
    sup.methodA();
}
```

I recognise that the code above wont work as an abstract class cannot be instantiated so im trying to do this:

```
{public static void main(String args[]){
    SuperClass sup= new SubClass();
    sup.methodA(); //Trying to call method in original superclass
}
```

Comment: You should post an example of code instead of trying to describe it in words.

Comment: You haven't included the part where you are actually trying to do the thing you asked about. Just an example super/sub class doesn't do much of anything.

Comment: No, you cannot do that - that would invalidate the concept of overridding a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create anonymous class that extends Super or a sub class that wont override `methodA()`.
Here is an example of the former approach:

```
    SuperClass sup= new SuperClass(){};
    sup.methodA();
```

Comment: I agree that this solves the "immediate" problem. But still it is the wrong approach. But still have my vote for the pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that "from the outside".

That is the whole purpose / idea of polymorphism - the exact method to invoke solely depends on the class of the object the method is invoked on.

In other words: you have to step back and fix your design. If you want to invoke a base class method, then you need a base class object - not a subclass one!

Meaning: there is no easy fix. Instead you should carefully review your requirements and then come up with a class hierarchy that helps you implementi these requirements.

I agree that the solution outlined by tsolakp would be working - but make no mistake: it is nothing but a (dirty) bandaid that fixes a symptom. You better invest your time in fixing the root cause which lies in a broken oo design.

Comment: It depends on the usage. I have used the anonymous approach in unit testing which I think is acceptable.

Comment: As said - if I wouldn't believe in a certain value to your answer I wouldn't have voted for it.